# Magento2 admin Panel Error

Tags: magento2, admin

When I have install Magento from localhost to Live environment. Front End of Website working fine But Admin Panel Shows error "This page isn’t working mysite.com redirected you too many times."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@praful can you please check in DB table **core_config_data**. In path column search for `web/url/redirect_to_base` is set to 0 if it is set to 1.

Comment: @ Sanjay Vadadoriya Dont have any data into the database

Comment: @praful can you please try with command php bin/magento config:set web/url/redirect_to_base 0. 

check after clean cache.

Comment: Its also not working same error for admin

Comment: @praful remove rm -rf var/ generated/ and clear cookies too!

Comment: I was do that But Same Result. Not working Admin Panel

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using custom url for admin and disable the use_custom in database:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%admin/url/%'

| admin/url/custom          | default | 0        | https://www.yourlivesite.com/admincustom/ |
| admin/url/use_custom      | default | 0        | 1                             |
| admin/url/use_custom_path | default | 0        | 0
```

set them to

```
 | admin/url/custom          | default | 0        | https://www.localurl.com/admin/ |
    | admin/url/use_custom      | default | 0        | 0                             |
    | admin/url/use_custom_path | default | 0        | 0
```

Do :

```
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: By using Select query I am not getting any data.

Comment: open your database in phpmyadmin , and manually go to core_config_data table , search for path admin/url

Comment: Like this https://cl.ly/376f9c2507bb . Or you can try the query again , i forgot a typo on that '

Comment: By this also not getting any data. Mysql return empty data.

Comment: I add this ' also but then also get empty data

Comment: Try the phpadmin method , what version of magento 2 are you using ?

Comment: yes i am using magento 2.3

Comment: im trying this on 2.3 and it working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103601/discussion-between-praful-and-ylgen-guxholli).

Comment: do you have magerun ? if you have it you can run **n98-magerun2 config:store:get admin/url/** , if you dont this can help on installing https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2 , open the bash and run the command